# Illegal base64 data at input byte 68

Tags: go, base64, decode

I am getting: error: illegal base64 data at input byte 68
When passing in base64_edcode string into base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str):

the string is:

```
TbHl6ijhdKwXklzOkw5+/r5Yac0kED8Iyp/7suphsFLHSJAUGM8vZHeroTeJ9eF4PePO5A
```

but put the string into php base64_decoed is ok
result is 0000000000bd583f958a7018c9[11,"string",8641231,1111]

Why?

Comment: That "result" doesn't at all match your Base64 string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because it's not a valid Base 64 string.  It's missing the end padding.  With proper padding:

```
TbHl6ijhdKwXklzOkw5+/r5Yac0kED8Iyp/7suphsFLHSJAUGM8vZHeroTeJ9eF4PePO5A==
```

[it works](https://play.golang.org/p/DiGpJq5qRzT), or you can tell the decoder [not to look for padding](https://play.golang.org/p/R7lWDmUSRiH):

```
    out, err := base64.StdEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding).DecodeString(str)
```